# How to use the occupancy grid in the global planner?

Tags: slam, navigation, base-global-planner, costmap, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everybody,

I am trying to create a path planner, that plans reliable paths in SLAM maps.
Therefore I don't want to use the costmap, which doesn't work with probabilities anymore but the occupancy grid.
But I don't know how to access it in my global planner...
Can anybody help me?

Cheers,
Earthgrazer

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244816/how-to-use-the-occupancy-grid-in-the-global-planner?/) by [Earthgrazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/27252/earthgrazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simplest way would be to subscribe to the `map` topic (assuming that's where the SLAM node is publishing to) This would give you access to the `nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid` messages corresponding to the latest map. You'll probably also need to subscribe to the `map_metadata` topic as well, which will contain the `nav_msgs/MapMetaData` messages.

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0